# How to change duration of "remember me" cookie in laravel 9?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm using laravel 9 and implementing login authentication manually without the [laravel starter kit](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authentication#starter-kits), I've read a lot of questions like this but most of the answers only apply to those using the starter kit, I've also read some of the other answers without the starter kit but most of them don't work.

This is my login method in the controller:

```
public function auth()
{
    // validation
    request()->validate([
        'emailOrUsername' => ['required'],
        'password' => ['required']
    ]);

    // Check if the user clicks "remember me" in the login form
    $remember = (request()->remember) ? true : false;

    // If login using email
    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => request()->emailOrUsername, 'password' => request()->password], $remember)) {
        request()->session()->regenerate();
        return redirect()->intended('/dashboard');
    }
    // If login using username
    else if (Auth::attempt(['username' => request()->emailOrUsername, 'password' => request()->password], $remember)) {
        request()->session()->regenerate();
        return redirect()->intended('/dashboard');
    } 
    // If incorrect credentials
    else {
        return back()->with('errorAlert', 'Maaf, email/username atau password yang anda masukkan salah');
    }
}
```

I also noticed that it seems the default cookie duration for "remember me" is set in the [`Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard`](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.html) namespace (but I didn't find the explanation in the official laravel documentation), I see that class has a [`setRememberDuration()`](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.html#method_setRememberDuration) method to change the duration of the "remember me" cookie, but I don't know how to properly call it, I've used `Auth::setRememberDuration(1000)` but it doesn't work. Is there any other way to set the "remember me" cookie duration using that method? Or is there another way to change the duration without using that method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set it in config/auth.php :

```
'guards' => [
    'web'     => [
        'driver'   => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'remember' => now()->addDays(7)->diffInMinutes(),
    ]
],
```

it's then used by the AuthManager :

```
if (isset($config['remember'])) {
    $guard->setRememberDuration($config['remember']);
}
```

edit:

For future readers, this answers only work from Laravel 8.65.0

Comment: Thanks very much! This is the only solution that worked for me from many other answers

Comment: @Lk77 in your example, why do you calculate the minutes using the current time? It's a static value. Your example could be 7 * 1440 or just 10080

Comment: @JoeNiland yes it could be, i think it's clearer that way, if i just put 10080 it's not obvious that it's 7 days. And it's cached anyway by laravel so this has no impact. But it's up to you, if you prefer to put the raw value, go for it.

Comment: @Lk77 I understand using 7 * 1440 for clarity, but there's no need to get the current time as the config value is static. It's true that config is sometimes cached, but not always.